# How can i implement my Function in my trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

Hello everyone i am using an iban checker in PLSQL to check if the user filled in a right IBAN.

I have looked up the function on internet it compiles now i need to put in a trigger but it gives an error i have tried this

when  the user enters an iban nummer on the APEX appication and the ibannummers is wrong the trigger needs to do it work

This is my function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION CheckIBANNUMMBER(
      pIBAN IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR IS
      lResult     INTEGER;
      ResulText   Varchar(250);
      IBAN        VARCHAR2(256);
      IBAN_Digits VARCHAR2(256);
      l_mod       NUMBER;
      lTmp        VARCHAR2(8);
      lSCnt       INTEGER := 5;
      i           INTEGER := 1;

---

      FUNCTION fn_GetIBANDigits RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
        lChar   VARCHAR2(1);
        lNumber INTEGER;
        lString VARCHAR2(255);
      BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(IBAN) LOOP
          lChar := SUBSTR(IBAN, i, 1);
          BEGIN
            lNumber := ASCII(lChar);
            IF lNumber > 47 AND lNumber < 58 THEN
              -- It's number 0 ... 9
              lString := lString || TO_CHAR(lNumber - 48);
            ELSE
              lString := lString || TO_CHAR(lNumber - 55);
            END IF;
          END;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN lString;
      END fn_GetIBANDigits;

---

     BEGIN
      IBAN := SUBSTR(pIBAN, 5) || SUBSTR(pIBAN, 1, 4);

      IBAN_Digits := fn_GetIBANDigits;

      LOOP
        lTmp := SUBSTR(IBAN_Digits, i, lSCnt);
        EXIT WHEN lTmp IS NULL;

        IF l_mod IS NULL THEN
          l_mod := MOD( TO_NUMBER(lTmp), 97);
        ELSE
          l_mod := MOD(TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(l_mod) || lTmp), 97);
        END IF;

        i := i + lSCnt;
      END LOOP;

      IF l_mod = 1 THEN
        lResult := 1;
        ResulText := 'The given IBAN is correct';
      ELSE
        lResult := 0;
        ResulText := 'The given IBAN is incorrect';
      END IF;

      RETURN(ResulText);
    END CheckIBANNUMMBER;
```

and this is the trigger i made

```
create or replace trigger "T_CHECKIBAN"
BEFORE
insert or update on "PAYMENTS"
for each row
begin
if CHECKIBAN(new.IBAN) = 0 then raise_application_error(-20500,'Wrong IBANNUMMBER');
end;
```

Comment: Hi @Harry, what is the error you get ? Thanks!

Comment: Your function name is: CheckIBANNUMMBER and you call it CHECKIBAN ?

Comment: @VBokšić succces with compilation error

Comment: @VBokšić my function name i Checibannumber and my trigger name is checkiban

Comment: And you want to call your function "Checibannumber" from your trigger? Show me the line where you call the Checibannumber function from your trigger :) You will see there is no such line because you are calling the wrong function name...

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual column and a `CHECK` constraint then your validity checks are in the DDL statement for the table rather than being in another castle (i.e. a trigger):

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION CheckIBANNumber(
  pIBAN IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  lResult     INTEGER;
  ResulText   Varchar(250);
  IBAN        VARCHAR2(256);
  IBAN_Digits VARCHAR2(256);
  l_mod       NUMBER;
  lTmp        VARCHAR2(8);
  lSCnt       INTEGER := 5;
  i           INTEGER := 1;

---

  FUNCTION fn_GetIBANDigits RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    lChar   VARCHAR2(1);
    lNumber INTEGER;
    lString VARCHAR2(255);
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(IBAN) LOOP
      lChar := SUBSTR(IBAN, i, 1);
      BEGIN
        lNumber := ASCII(lChar);
        IF lChar BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN
          -- It's number 0 ... 9
          lString := lString || lChar;
        ELSIF lChar BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' THEN 
          lString := lString || TO_CHAR(ASCII(lChar) - 55);
        END IF;
      END;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN lString;
  END fn_GetIBANDigits;

---

BEGIN
  IBAN := SUBSTR(pIBAN, 5) || SUBSTR(pIBAN, 1, 4);

  IBAN_Digits := fn_GetIBANDigits;

  LOOP
    lTmp := SUBSTR(IBAN_Digits, i, lSCnt);
    EXIT WHEN lTmp IS NULL;

    IF l_mod IS NULL THEN
      l_mod := MOD( TO_NUMBER(lTmp), 97);
    ELSE
      l_mod := MOD(TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(l_mod) || lTmp), 97);
    END IF;

    i := i + lSCnt;
  END LOOP;

  IF l_mod = 1 THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END CheckIBANNumber;
/
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data (
  Country      VARCHAR2(20),
  IBAN         VARCHAR2(50),
  IBANValidity NUMBER(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CheckIBANNumber( iban ) ),
  CONSTRAINT IsValidIBAN CHECK ( IBANValidity = 1 )
);
```

Then (with test data from wikipedia):

```
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Belgium', 'BE71 0961 2345 6769' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'France', 'FR76 3000 6000 0112 3456 7890 189' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Germany', 'DE91 1000 0000 0123 4567 89' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Greece', 'GR96 0810 0010 0000 0123 4567 890' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Romania', 'RO09 BCYP 0000 0012 3456 7890' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Saudi Arabia', 'SA44 2000 0001 2345 6789 1234' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Spain', 'ES79 2100 0813 6101 2345 6789' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'Switzerland', 'CH56 0483 5012 3456 7800 9' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( Country, IBAN ) VALUES ( 'United Kingdom', 'GB98 MIDL 0700 9312 3456 78' );
```

succeeds, and:

```
 SELECT * FROM test_data;
```

outputs:

> ```
> COUNTRY        | IBAN                              | IBANVALIDITY
> :------------- | :-------------------------------- | -----------:
> Belgium        | BE71 0961 2345 6769               |            1
> France         | FR76 3000 6000 0112 3456 7890 189 |            1
> Germany        | DE91 1000 0000 0123 4567 89       |            1
> Greece         | GR96 0810 0010 0000 0123 4567 890 |            1
> Romania        | RO09 BCYP 0000 0012 3456 7890     |            1
> Saudi Arabia   | SA44 2000 0001 2345 6789 1234     |            1
> Spain          | ES79 2100 0813 6101 2345 6789     |            1
> Switzerland    | CH56 0483 5012 3456 7800 9        |            1
> United Kingdom | GB98 MIDL 0700 9312 3456 78       |            1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc773db2a53006358b665c4b1f98ce94)*

Answer (score 0):

Your code, edited:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_CHECKIBAN
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON PAYMENTS
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF CheckIBANNUMMBER(:new.IBAN) = 0 /* new --> :new, CHECKIBAN -- > CheckIBANNUMMBER*/
    THEN
        raise_application_error(-20500, 'Wrong IBANNUMMBER');
    END IF; /* added END IF */
END;
```

I removed double quotes, because you only need them if you want to use lower case characters.

Also notice that your function gives `ResulText`, while it seems that it should return `lResult` instead; and even, you are using a `varchar2` return value to handle a number.

If you only want this function to check whether the IBAN is correct or not, you should edit your function as follows (`ResulText` is unuseful here):

```
create or replace FUNCTION CheckIBANNUMMBER(
      pIBAN IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN number IS /* return a number */
    ...
      RETURN(lResult); /* return 0/1 */
    END CheckIBANNUMMBER;
```

Comment: It gives the following error error ORA-06502: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Comment: As said, you are using a function that returns a varchar and comparing this result with a number; you need to edit your function

Comment: @Harry It probably returns `ORA-06502` because your IBAN has spaces in it and `ASCII(' ') = 32` and `32 - 55` is negative and `TO_CHAR` on a negative number is going to fail.

Comment: @MT0 - *"TO_CHAR on a negative number is going to fail."* - are you sure?

Comment: @APC My bad phrasing (its not going to fail there but it will be the direct cause of a later failure) ... its going to insert `-23` into the middle of the sub-string and then when you use `TO_NUMBER( lTmp )` later there will be a `-` sign somewhere in it and it is likely to either raise an exception (if the `-` character is in the middle of the string) or cause the result to be incorrect (if the `-` is the first character).